# Authentication: API Server (loopback+JWT) vs Node Server (Nodejs+JWT)

Tags: mongodb, rest, api, jwt, loopbackjs

My stack: MongoDB -> API with loopback -> Nodejs -> and Reactjs in the frontend (each part on a different server)

If I have the logic in a node server, and I have the API in another Node server. And I have to authenticate my users in both:

I have to make the token for each server or this can be shared between both?

I understand JWT makes a token in the server and just this server can decrypt it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same token while you use the same signing key.

If you use a symmetric key (HMAC) then the secret key must be shared between two server, because the key is used to sign and verify the token

If you use an asymmetric key (RSA) the token is signed with the private key and verified with the public. Then you can issue the tokens in one server and distribute the public key to the other, or even the clients. Then the security issues for sharing the secret keys are reduced. The drawback in this case could be that tokens are issued in one server. If you need to issue in both then probably a symmetric key is more suitable